Which permissions are required to execute a Docker-promote (REST-API)?
The official documentation lacks details about which specific permissions are nowadays required to run a docker promotion with this approach: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/promote-docker-image. Can anyone shed light on this?
I expect to run a Docker promotion that, as a result, copies the Docker image from a source to a target repo inside Artifactory, with the REST API above.
Thank you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As stated in the Docker Promote API wiki page. This API will require you to use an authenticated and privileged user (i.e. a user that has read permissions to the source repository and deploy/write permissions to the target repository).

Thank you for your comment. The Docker Promote API wiki page states  "Security: Requires a privileged user". Can you please add a source/reference that this is the same as "A user that has read permissions to the source repository and deploy/write permissions to the target repository". Other pieces of the overall documentation use other approaches, see e.g. here. That one states "Security: Requires a user with 'deploy' permissions (can be anonymous)". Thanks.
